# importing a good mesh

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, file-format, svg

Im importing and svg file and when i go to edit mode get some 1000's mesh and edges,etc. Is there a file to get a clean mesh. Image is attach object mode look fine but when turn to edit mode 1000's of mesh. Is there any other file format which we can get a clean mesh. [image]
[image]

blender file [image]

file disappear [image]

[image]

Comment: Mesh looks alright to me honestly, this is a fairly complicated pattern that requires a lot of polygons to represent. Might be simpler using ngons but the importer and simple conversion from curve to mesh is unlikely to generate these.

Comment: To get that much detail you need many vertices. If you want to work with simpler geometry then do not convert your curves to mesh after importing SVGs

Comment: a file attached problem im getting as soon as the remesh added it disappears

Comment: To use the remesh modifier your mesh must have volume. You need to extrude all your geometry like in @Paul Gonet's example below, then the Remesh modifier will work.

Comment: i have tried adding but its not working with my mesh can u plz try with my mesh

Answer (score 3):

There is no other file format that will guarantee a better mesh topology, unless you import as NURBS, but Blender can not import NURBS nor handle that kind of geometric complexity.

As TLousky mentions the results you are getting are totally normal and expected when converting a bezier curve into a mesh. However I would advise to not convert the SVG curve into a mesh, unless you specifically need to and only *when* you need to.

Keep it as a Bezier Curve object as long as possible, it's non destructive,  will be easier to edit and maintain while being easily editable as a bezier curve handles.

Also have a look at [my answer about cleanup techniques](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/56352/19307) for bezier curve objects, useful both for keeping as curve or before converting to mesh for a cleaner topology.

Have in mind that converting Bezier Objects into meshes will **always** leave a mesh with uneven topology and lots of triangulated edges. You may later clean them up a bit by turning flat faces into NGons.

That won't improve topology nor benefit unwrapping or editing, but it may give a cleaner viewport.

[image]

Comment: a file attached problem im getting as soon as the remesh added it disappears

Comment: and in ur image after u clicking the face what hot key u have press u got that normal and other options

Comment: Press `Shift +G` in edit mode to bring up the *Select Grouped* menu

Answer (score 1):

You may always improve the geometry after importing using the ***Remesh Modifier***.
[image]

Extrude your mesh downwards to give it some depth. Add the modifier and experiment with the *Octree Depth* and *Scale* values. 
[image]

To see the modifier's effect in *Object Mode* go to *Object* header and check the ***Wire*** checkbox in the *Display* panel.
[image]

---

***EDIT:*** Steps to follow in your case:

- select thw whole mesh (<kbd>A</kbd>) in *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>W</kbd>-->*Remove Doubles*
- with the whole mesh selected press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Cursor to Selected*. Enter *Object Mode* and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>-->*Origin to 3D Cursor*. Then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and finally <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Selection to Cursor*

[image]

- go to *Object* header and check the ***Wire*** checkbox in the *Display* panel
- extrude your whole mesh downwards (<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>Z</kbd>)
- go to *Object Mode* and add the ***Remesh Modifier***. Increase the *Octree Depth* and play with a *Scale* value. ***Uncheck*** the ***Remove Disconnected Pieces*** checkbox
- **apply the modifier**

[image]

- delete extruded vertices
- select the top ones and scale them (<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>Z</kbd>,<kbd>0</kbd>) to make them flat (if needed)

[image]

Here's the result:
[image]

And a .blend file: [image]

Comment: a file attached problem im getting as soon as the remesh added it disappears

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check it out.

Comment: thanks for replying me and getting that image. as i have notice that 4 image are not similar as i have attach the image/ It looks good from a view but when zoom its not similar.

Comment: Sometimes some modifiers don't work perfectly, so you have to tweak some things by hand. As you have the clean divisions in your mesh, you may try to delete three patterns and give the remaining one an *Array Modifier* with the *Count* number of 4.