# Fixing a complex boolean messy mesh

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I have a map that I needed to use a boolean modifier on to cut out the water systems from a textured plane. It's messy with lots of verts and now I have problems with the face rendering. How would you suggest fixing something like this? Thanks for any ideas[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDSBu.png)

Comment: Try using *remesh modifier*. Here's the solution to the similar problem you have: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65555/importing-a-good-mesh

Comment: Thanks Paul, I tried that but it didn't work too well, the mesh distorts and I lose the detail I need...

Comment: Please post your .blend via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and I'll try to help you.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, I ended up fixing it by manually going through and adding more qauds and vertices to problematic areas... took a long time but fixed all the problems - I'll post the answer for others

Comment: Is there a reason you needed to use a boolean modifier, instead of something like making the water systems transparent in the shader?

Comment: Hey Dale, I used blender-osm (https://gumroad.com/l/blender-osm) to import the water data and needed the water level to sit below a textured map (on the plane). So boolean was the method I used to cut out the hole in order to extrude the edges down and place a water texture that sits lower... couldn't think of another way of doing it... even to make a transparent shader you'd need the geometry there in the first place right? How would you go about creating that clean geometry?

Comment: @Dan another way to do this with much cleaner geometry is to use a displace modifier on a highly subdivided plane. The image of the water can be used to push down the faces where you want the water. Then you can apply the modifier and decimate the plane to end up with a highly optimized mesh. See this related link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42640/is-it-possible-to-use-a-displacement-map-without-having-real-geometry/42641#42641