# Why am I getting these spikes after Solidifed an SVG file?

Tags: extrude, svg

So anytime I import an SVG and then apply the solidify tool, it will give me these weird spikes.

How can I fix this?

Here’s footage of what I mean: https://youtu.be/UqrxbEj0GOs

Comment: Have you tried instead increasing the `extrude` field inside the curve > geometry properties ?

Comment: [Please provide some context and explanation, don't just post a link to a video](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49979 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65555

Answer (score 0):

I remember having something similar to this problem. What I had to do was in edit mode, there were vertices that were sticking out for no reason at all. I am not sure why they do this, but what I had to do was delete the vertices that were sticking out in edit mode. I hope this helps!