# Why does my curve not fill correctly?

Tags: bezier-curves, svg

I have imported a .svg of a logo that's pretty complex. When extruding it looks quite good but I want more than the outlines to be filled.

When switching to 2D and fill both sides it does not fill inside the curve (yellow on left picture) but rather randomly (right picture).

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to make the logo solid?

Best regards,
Daniel

[image]

Comment: Things to look for: open paths, overlapping or intersecting segments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SVG Curve Incorrectly Rendered](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/svg-curve-incorrectly-rendered)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75728 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52825 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65555 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56344