# After importing svg, [mesh from curve] creates annoying results?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, optimization, svg

I have created some top views of buildings from AI CC2015 with simple paths, exporting to SVG files.

After importing in Blender 2.73, I want to extrude them to make buildings. I pressed *Mesh to Curve* & *Tris to *Quads*. Some of them look just alright, while some of them become weird with overlapping faces.

[image]

Is there anyway to clean/fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you might want to do a boolean Union on the Paths in Illustrator before exporting as SVG. this will avoid any overlapping geometry and make the conversion cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure there are no overlapping segments in your curves before conversion, otherwise remove doubles after conversion to mesh.

Before conversion to mesh make sure your curve is set to *2D* and the *Fill* is set to either just *Front* or *Back*, not *Both*

Also have in mind that converting curves to mesh will always lead do triangulation, and not all curve shapes can be filled entirely by quads, nor without NGons.

Also, if your curve had wholes in them, additional edges will appear, because the mesh structure doesn't support islands. That means there can't be totally disconnected groups of edges sharing the same faces, like in tha building with the whole in the middle.

See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56344/reducing-internal-faces-generated-by-extensive-curve-extrusion/56352#56352) for more cleanup techniques