# Weird triangles on flat surface - extruded svg

Tags: rendering, normals, svg

I extruded an svg file (vector curves) and am getting all this weirdness (triangles visible on flat surfaces) when I render it. 
[image]
I'm sure this is a simple answer, but what is going on?

Comment: You need to clean up your mesh, before extruding and beveling it. Limited Dissolve, and judicious removal of Doubles should take you most, if not all of the way. Flat Ngons would be fine, here, unless you need to print or deform, your text.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66738/after-importing-svg-mesh-from-curve-creates-annoying-results/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56344/reducing-internal-faces-generated-by-extensive-curve-extrusion/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve/

Answer (score 1):

I realized I had a "Solidify" modifier applied. Took that off and it fixed it.