# Bevel Problems with imported SVG

Tags: edges, bevel

i'm new to blender so please be nice.
I imported a SVG (Logo) from Illustrator and want to bevel the edges, but it creates strange connections in the corners.

I didn't do a double extrude. After importing I changed it to a curve, then to a mesh and back to a curve (not to get weird faces) and then I used F to fill the shape. 
Then I apply clean up.
Next I extrude my shapes and apply bevel edge cut. 
sorry If the question is already answered somewhere but I couldn't make it work.[image: the left and right corner shouldn't be connected like that]

Comment: click delete and select limited dissolve

Comment: Take a look at the bevel modifier https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/bevel.html and the Limit Method - Angle.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75728/how-to-fix-imported-svg-from-inkscape-with-wrong-fill/75736 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66738/after-importing-svg-mesh-from-curve-creates-annoying-results/66742 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82188/fill-along-the-front-of-a-path-of-an-svg/82200