# Why does the mesh look complicated when I import the SVG file?

Tags: mesh, node-editor, import, wireframe, svg

I think there is some conversion error when importing SVG into blender. As you can see in the picture, the mesh is complex, so I think, it's hard to make a material. is there a way to remove the dirty mesh inside the shape?

[image]

Comment: could you please share the original svg file? Yes it often doesn't give good result when you convert from curve to mesh, you need to make some corrections afterward if you want something cleaner

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66738/after-importing-svg-mesh-from-curve-creates-annoying-results/66742#66742

Comment: If you have created svg file in Inkscape, you may need to covert strokes to paths beforehand. Blender doesn't recognise strokes in Inkscape.

Comment: @RitaGeraghty I don't use inkcape, I use Affinity Designer. However, Adobe Illustrator is the same result.

Comment: @moonboots Can I upload the file here? I didn't see the ability to upload files.

Comment: copy paste the address of this page then upload here: blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: @moonboots Thank you for your kind.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos As a beginner, it's a little difficult for me. I solved this problem by using the shortcut "F". However, there was another problem. If you don't mind, I hope you can help me through the link below. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/151357/why-is-the-thickness-of-the-object-bent