# Extruding svg-created curves with holes

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, edges, bevel, svg

I am trying to get a workflow going for svg → 3d model in blender → cnc router mill.

I hope to create a clean bevel on the outer and inner perimeters on the model after extruding the svg. I tried after converting from curve to mesh ([After importing svg, [mesh from curve] creates annoying results?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66738/after-importing-svg-mesh-from-curve-creates-annoying-results/)) but the geometry still has unnecessary triangles even after limited dissolve and removing doubles. Is there a better way to do this to get just the nodes for outer and inner perimeters? Part of Duarte Farrajota Ramos' answers involves curves with holes in them, which is exactly what I have.

Here are the problems I am running into:

[image]
I also don't understand why part of my model (converted from curves to mesh) has a bunch of non manifold edges (highlighted in orange) while the top half doesn't. Solidify gives me a different set of problems.

[image]

Random edges that couldn't be dissolved? I want the geometry to be as clean as possible. What are these?

[image: here's the sv]

Here is what it looked like on illustrator. I guess I could take out a few nodes. But I'm not sure that's what creating problems.

[image] Cut this from svg using 2d profile cut and a roundover bit. I want this to be a clean 3D model! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The main rule is a Face cannot have holes. So then you try to dissolve edges, Blender dissolve as many edges as it can, but some edges remains because where is no way to remove them without making a hole in a face