# Is it possible to colour or put textures on Bevel curves?

Tags: texturing, bevel

So with my model, I've been struggling to create hair because it always looked weird or off and recently I discovered the "Bevel Curve" addon and it's an absolute lifesaver.

So I converted the bevels into mesh to colour it, except it lags blender like crazy and I need this model for a video game I'm currently developing called Candles(so I can't upload the model, sorry) but I was wondering, is it possible to put a texture on a bevel curve like you would mesh or any other method or giving it colour?

Comment: You can assign materials to curves much like you can with meshes. Texturing is a bit more limited because you can't really unwrap, but there are automatically generated UV coordinates in the *Object Data > Texture Space * panel, they are limited but allow some level of control.

Comment: From how I do it now(because I'm still not that experienced with blender) you go into the UV editing window and press U to unwrap the model and it makes that appear in the left window where you can then apply the texture. 

Unfortunately I don't know how to do this with materials on curves, how would I go about doing this? Any good tutorials you can recommend? P:

Comment: Like I said you can't. You can not unwrap a curve object without explicitly converting to mesh first, which defeats the purpose. All you can do is use the built-in generated UV coordinates. Also you don't use the *UV Image Editor* to "appky tge textures" it's a common mistake you only used to unwrap, textures are then used through a material

Comment: Also if blender lags when you convert curves to mesh there is something wrong with your curves. [Try cleaning them](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56344/reducing-internal-faces-generated-by-extensive-curve-extrusion) up a bit before conversion

Comment: Not at the computer right now I'll try and post a proper answer later tonight when I'm back at the computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign materials to curves just like you would on any mesh with a few limitations.

Just create multiple material slots and in *Edit Mode* pick a vertex and press *Assign* to apply it to the complete corresponding spline. Only limitation is you can only apply one single material per spline, not per segment.

[image: Curve Materials]

Under the *Properties Window > Object Data (Curve) > Texture Space* you can turn on *Use UVs* for basic simple automated UV coordinates generation.

[image: Curve UVs]

They are limited in that they stretch for longer segments and give uneven texture density, but will do for basic stuff.

Anyway if you want to export this for a game engine I guess there is really no way around converting to mesh and manually unwrapping it properly. You may keep the original object as curve in case you need to go back and edit something, do the conversion on a duplicate for safe keeping.

After conversion to mesh the basic Automatic UVs are preserved, so you have somewhere to start. If these are enough check if they are also preserved when exporting the file to a game engine.

Also have in mind that if your Blender lags after converting your curves to mesh there may be too much geometry, and that it will also likely cause problems in the game engine. Consider [simplifying your curve geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56344/reducing-internal-faces-generated-by-extensive-curve-extrusion) before converting to mesh.