Gothic Pointed Arch Window
I have a problem that I don't know how to make the following window as good as possible. I have watched tutorial videos which have not helped me as a whole. I've tried drawing the window in LibreCAD, but when I try to follow the lines I drew, they don't look the way I want them to look in the original image.
I would like your help on how to model this window as easily as possible in Blender? What modifiers should I use or what method should I use? And what is the best modifier/method in modelling gothic architectures.
The most problematic part was:

creating the arch,
creating the three circle in the larger circle. (without cutting each other) and adding the arch also.




https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56344/reducing-internal-faces-generated-by-extensive-curve-extrusion
